# is it offensive to say "he looks like a player" using the female form for "a player"?

Tags: gender

I was just practicing on duolingo and it suggested the possible translations for *he looks like a player* as:

> Er sieht wie ein Spieler aus

or

> Er sieht wie eine Spielerin aus

Would the second form be a mocking comment to say he looks like a girl player?

Comment: In the context of looking or acting like a player, it seems the word player has made its way into the German (youth) language. You could say "Du bist echt ein Player"/"Er/sie sieht aus wie ein Player".

Comment: Without more context I would assume that the second translation is simply wrong.

Comment: Assuming that you mean a player in the figurative sense (otherwise the original English sentence wouldn't make much sence), both translations are wrong. 'Spieler' is not used in that sense in German.

Comment: Was ist denn gemeint, mit Player? Ein Sportler, ein Zocker, ein Schauspieler, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the second one would surely be understood as a male person looking like a female. This may be intended ("Du wirfst wie ein Mädchen!"), but may be offensive from a gender point of view (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjJQBjWYDTs).

Comment: Ich dachte immer, man sagt "Du wirfst wie ein Vegetarier" ? :-)

Comment: @Burki Ich dachte immer, Vegetarier wären zu schwach zum Werfen? :-D

Comment: :D nice ones. Agreeing with what Thorsten said, but I would usually actually say »Er spielt wie ein Mädchen« or »… wie ein Waschweib«, just because it makes the female part more clear. Note that all these are pejorative so use with caution ;)

Comment: @Jan: "Waschweiber" are notoriously strong, albeit very talkative - don't mess with these. Not the same as "wie ein Mädchen".

Comment: @Stephie Correct. And both differ from »wie eine Spielerin« by being stronger in different ways. Point just being that the *Spielerin* in herself is likely too weak to be significant. If I'm going to insult someone by calling them feminine, I'm going to be more obvious and deviating while doing so ;)